# Next.js how to apply async result list onto components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

If I set constant array as default value, directly instead of `async/await` , my grid is working properly. When it comes to connecting network API into my result set, the console log within my component `TestGrid` as jsx does not print my items.

Would you please tell me how can we insert updated result list into components ?

Below is my working:

**TestGrid Component**

```
const TestGrid = ({ appliedStyle, itemStyle, resultList }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(resultList);
  });
  let jsx = [];
  Array.from(resultList).forEach((cardItem) => {
    console.log("item :" + JSON.stringify(cardItem));
    jsx.push(
      <div className={itemStyle}>
        <Container className={styles.container_item_1}>
          <Typography variant="h2" color="white" align="center">
            {cardItem.title}
          </Typography>
          {typeof cardItem.figure != "undefined" &&
            typeof cardItem.unit != "undefined" && (
              <Typography variant="h2" color="white" align="center">
                {cardItem.figure + " " + cardItem.unit}
              </Typography>
            )}
          <br />
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div class={appliedStyle}>{jsx}</div>;
};

export default TestGrid;
```

My **index.tsx**

```
async function getStaticRecycleKPI() {
  const notion = new Client({
    auth: "....",
  });

  const databaseId = "....";
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: databaseId,
  });

  var jsx: REcycleClass[] = [];
  response.results.forEach((employee: any) => {
    jsx.push(
      new REcycleClass(
        employee.properties.Title.title[0].plain_text,
        employee.properties.Number.number,
        employee.properties.Unit.rich_text[0].plain_text
      )
    );
  });

      console.log("resultList XX" + JSON.stringify(jsx));
      return jsx;
    }

class REcycleClass {
  title: string;
  figure: number;
  unit: string;

  constructor(name: string, amount: number, unit: string) {
    this.title = name;
    this.figure = amount;
    this.unit = unit;
  }
}

const recyclerKPI = getStaticRecycleKPI();
```

....

```
  <section id="recycle_kpi_content">
        <TestGrid
          appliedStyle="gchhkgrid3"
          itemStyle="squaredark"
          resultList={recyclerKPI}
        />
      </section>
```

P.S. Given result list as follows

```
  [{"title":"其他","figure":100,"unit":"kg"},{"title":"金屬回收","figure":100,"unit":"kg"},{"title":"廢紙回收","figure":100,"unit":"kg"},{"title":"回收總數","figure":3900,"unit":"kg"},{"title":"塑膠回收","figure":100,"unit":"kg"},{"title":"廚餘回收","figure":3400,"unit":"kg"}]
```